# Discrete Fourier series of an odd signal

Tags: fourier-series

Assuming the signal shown below :
[image]

I have found an expression for fourier series coeffecients as the following:
$$a_{k} = \frac{1}{5}+\frac{j}{5}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{5}k}$$

Which matches with what the books suggests as an answer.
My confusion is this : why are they not **purely imaginary** ?

I tried to prove this property the following way:
Signal is **real** and **even**:
$$\implies x[n] = x^{*}[n] = -x[-n] $$
with ***** denoting the conjugate.
And using properties of **conjugation**, **time-reversal** and **linearity** we get :
$$a_{k} = a^{*}_{-k} = -a_{-k} $$

Then I concluded :
$$a_{k} = -a_{-k} \implies a_{k}\  are\ odd\ in\ k$$
$$ a^{*}_{-k} = -a_{-k} \implies a_{k}\ are\ purely\ imaginary $$

What is wrong with all the above?
Is any step in my reasoning wrong or is the solution to the problem incorrect ?

Comment: What value should $x[0]$ have if the signal was odd?

Comment: @MattL. It should be zero, which is not the case here.

Comment: On a second look now, I see that there was a mistake in the assumption of "the signal is odd". I don't know how that escaped me. But is the proof sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that a purely odd signal should have purely imaginary coefficients.  Your signal, however, is not odd -- it is the sum of an odd part (most of the samples), and an even part (the nonzero sample at time = 0).